# Passing Method Call with arguments already specified

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to call a methodA with parameters already specified from another method.
So I want to pass the method call and arguments as a parameter to MethodB and once it's done some processing, call the MethodA with arguments specified.

I know i can pass the call as a methodB as a delegate parameter and then also pass the parameters like so :

```
static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            MethodB(1, 2, Add);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Add(int i, int j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i+j);
        }

static public class DelegateWithDelegateParameter
    {
        public static void MethodB(int param1, int param2, Action<int, int> dAction)
        {
            dAction(param1, param2);
        }
    }
```

Wondering, if it's possible to do this with the parameters already specified rather than having to pass parameters ParamA,ParamB to MethodB from Main already specified. Was just wondering. Hope this make sense, please let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: "if it's possible to do this with the parameters *already specified* rather than having to pass parameters ParamA,ParamB to MethodB from Main *already specified*." I'm not sure what you mean by "already specified" since you use it describe what you want to do and what you are doing in the example (which I assume is not what you want). Are you saying you want to pass a delegate that has no arguments based on a method that takes some parameters? Something like this: `Action a = () => Add(1, 2); a();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm following what you are asking, to get what you want you need to wrap your call to Add in a delegate that holds it's parameters.  This is easy to do using [lamda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) syntax:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    MethodB(() => Add(1, 2));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void Add(int i, int j)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i+j);
}

static public class DelegateWithDelegateParameter
{
    public static void MethodB(Action dAction)
    {
        dAction();
    }
}
```

The statement `() => Add(1,2)` creates a new `Action` delegate that is defined to call `Add()` with the parametes `1,2`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, jusy annoyed couldn't figure this out myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
static object InvokeMethod(Delegate method, params object[] args){
    return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}

static int Add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

static void Test(){
    Console.WriteLine(InvokeMethod(new Func<int, int, int>(Add), 5, 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through Delegate. declare a delegate first and hook your method to it like

```
public delegate void adddelegate(int a, int b);
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        adddelegate adddel = new adddelegate(Add);

        DelegateWithDelegateParameter.MethodB(1, 2, adddel);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Add(int i, int j)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + j);
    }
}

static public class DelegateWithDelegateParameter
{
    public static void MethodB(int param1, int param2, adddelegate dAction)
    {
        dAction(param1, param2);
    }
}
```